# Vectorise generation of all two letter permutations of alphabet letter in python

Tags: python, vectorization, processing-efficiency

The following python code generates a (650 elements) list of all two letter permutations of the uppercase alphabet letters:

```
import string
import itertools

UPPERCASE_ALPHABET = string.ascii_uppercase

# generate all permutation of two letters
two_letter_perms = itertools.permutations(UPPERCASE_ALPHABET, 2)

# convert tuples to string
digrams = []
for tl in two_letter_perms:
    digrams.append("".join(tl))

print(f"Generated a list of {len(digrams)} digrams.")
```

I am not succeeding in devising a vectorized or otherwise more efficient way of doing the last part instead of the for loop. Thanks for any help.